# Code::Blocks console app won't show output

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I've got an application in Code::Blocks, and it's the simple Hello, World traditional program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
}
```

The program builds and executes, but the output isn't shown. I checked the project properties in Code::Blocks and it is definitely set to console application. Any suggestions as to the problem?

Edit: The output only fails in the IDE. When run separately the resulting executable functions exactly as expected.

Comment: Maybe a silly question: Is the 'Pause after execution' checked? (It's under Type dropdown list)

Comment: I suggest run .exe (or binary output) in shell and check the output

Comment: I had the same problem when I installed mine, I'll try to remember but I was able to fix it quite easily.

Comment: @jrok: Yes, it is. The compiler shows other output after the program is finished and allows me to choose when to close the console.

Comment: Is it possible that stdout isn't getting flushed for some reason?

Comment: @Douglas: You mean the part where I wrote `std::endl;`?

Comment: Stdout is normally flushed on each new-line, and on program exit. But maybe something about how Code::Blocks is running it is preventing that? The whole line is outputted to stdout.

Comment: @DeadMG: were you ever able to figure this out? I'm having the same problem.  Compiler works except when used in the ide...

Comment: Not sure if anyone is still having this problem but for me it was AVG shield was blocking it.  Added the folder that my projects were in to the list of exceptions and it works fine now.  Hopefully this will save someone out there a little time

Comment: I was not able to figure out the problem- I uninstalled C::B and used VS instead. I was not running an antivirus.

Answer (score 8):

It's possible that you don't have `xterm` installed it.

If you are on Linux (Debian flavor) you can install it with your package manager like so:

`sudo apt-get install xterm`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set the terminal to launch the console applications. It can be done in the general environment settings.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem but it went away after I shut code blocks down and restarted.  I also shut down without saving changes to the perspective (if that matters).  It may be important that it happened right after I made an empty project and tried to make that empty project into a c++ console application.   When that didn't work I made a "console application" project (with the hello world) but it wouldn't show the console either.