# How can I get console output in code block IDE

Tags: c++, c

My code has everything ok! But I don't get any output on the console. 
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A simple question for you, Did you run it ?

Comment: Coming soon, where is semicolon located on my keyboard?

Comment: Running the program from the Windows GUI, the first time I saw a very brief console window outline on the screen, the second and subsequent times, I saw nothing (due to caching?). What happens when you run your program from a console?

Answer (score 1):

Click on build->run or hit Ctrl+F10 and a new CMD Window should pop up, showing you your "Hello world!".

Answer (score 1):

I think Anti-virus might be causing a problem for you. Try excluding the folder that contains your file. There was another question posted with same problem and for that excluding the folder worked. [Code::Blocks console app won't show output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554836/codeblocks-console-app-wont-show-output#comment20501153_7554836)

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this same problem on linux; installing `xterm` solved the problem for me.

See `Settings > Environment > General Settings > Terminal to launch console programs`

Comment: Changing to Terminal is probably preferable, but for installing xterm: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33893916/1599699

Answer (score 0):

Please include getchar() in the function before return statement. This happens because the computer is executing your program and doesn't wait for you to see the output. Including getchar(), at the end mandates it to wait for an input & in the meanwhile you can observe your output

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to use linux terminal, and it is tested by me.

```
gnome-terminal --geometry=80x20+300+240 -x
```